# Ruby, how to create a Rack::Request for testing purposes?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, request, rack

I have a library that take a `Rack::Request` and do stuff on it.

I would like to test it from an *unit test* and not from a *functional test*. So I have to create a `Rack::Request` instance on my own, how can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rack itself includes some unit tests for `Rack::Request`, you can use them as a starting point ([example](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/test/spec_request.rb#L8)).

```
Rack::Request.new(Rack::MockRequest.env_for("http://example.com:8080/", {"REMOTE_ADDR" => "10.10.10.10"}))
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Rack::MockRequest`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/mock.rb#L22) which is implemented for this purpose. See [these tests](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/test/spec_request.rb) for example usage.